# How can a muslim girl maintain good smell?

Tags: women

I'm a Muslim girl studying for dental surgeon in india. All through my childhood and teenage, i studied in qatar, we had air conditioning everywhere so it was easy to stick to the rule of forbidding perfume.. But when i came to india, it started becoming hard... Electricity goes off often in my college and,there are times when fans are switched off and we work near fire..n by the time college is over.. I'll be drenched in sweat..
I read that for a muslim cleanliness is a very major rule ...to be clean and smell clean....
while , sticking to the "forbid perfume " rule makes me very uncomfortable now... Is there any mild perfumes i can use?
Or will it still be haraam under all circumstances?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bismillah hir rahman nir raheem
As sallamu alaykum wa rahmatullahi wa baraktuhu.
May allah have mercy on you and me.
General rule is it is not halal for a woman to wear perfume outside her house or where she may come into contact with men who are not family.

> It was narrated from Abu Moosa (may Allaah be pleased with him) that the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “If a woman puts on perfume and passes by people so that they can smell her fragrance, then she is such and such,” and he spoke sternly - meaning an adulteress. Narrated by Abu Dawood (4173) and al-Tirmidhi (2786);

Even if you want to smell nice for sake of Allah and do what the men do when they attend the masjid it will be rewardable for the men and sin upon the women because.

> Zaynab, the wife of ‘Abd-Allaah ibn Mas’ood, said: The Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said to us: “If one of you attends the mosque, let her not put on perfume.” Narrated by Muslim (443).

However from the scholars i have consulted they have said if there is no fear men will smell her it is fine and they gave the following evidence

> It was narrated that ‘Aa’ishah (may Allaah be pleased with her) said: We used to go out with the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) to Makkah, and we would apply perfume to our foreheads when entering ihraam, then if one of us sweated it would run down her face, and the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) would see it but he would not rebuke her. 
>   Because in those days when making hajj the caravans were separate from the men. 
>   Narrated by Abu Dawood (1830)
>
> Shaykh ‘Abd al-‘Azeez ibn Baaz (may Allaah have mercy on him) said in Majmoo’ al-Fataawa (10/40):
>
> It is permissible for her to apply perfume if she is going out to a place of women and is not going to pass by men in the street.

So in your situation if your in class with men just use deodorant in the mornings etc because its smell doesn't go beyond you and during the day underneath your clothes also change your clothes regularly etc and use other beauty techniques which are halal as long as they do not cause men to smell you in class.
And allah knows best.

[Source of the quotes](https://islamqa.info/en/102329)

Comment: When you copy-paste from [islamqa](https://islamqa.info/en/102329) you must give a reference to your source. Also read in our [Meta](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/953/the-copy-paste-issue-revisited)!

Comment: As sallamu alaykum akhi alkareem sometimes the hadith or statement of scholar can quickly be found on internet and saves time typing it in hence i copy and paste only the hadith or statement wether on qa or other than it.l rather than type in word for word.